# Determine RasEntry structure size use RasGetEntryProperties in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ras

I'm trying to create a DUN entry.

I am calling RasGetEntryProperties with a lpRasEntry parameter of null.  This should return the structure size in the lpdwEntryInfoSize parameter.  Instead it returns an error - ERROR_INVALID_SIZE.

How do I call the RasGetEntryProperties function to get the RasEntry structure size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377535.aspx) says that `Error_Invalid_Size` is the error when the `dwSize` field fo the `RasEntry` record is incorrect. If the function was able to read that field, then you did not provide a null pointer for the `lpRasEntry` parameter as you claim you did. The Microsoft documentation says "null," and in Delphi, the reserved word [`nil`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types) designates the null pointer. Do not get confused with the *function* named [`Null`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Variants.Null); it designates the special [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant_Types) value.

Based on the documentation, you should have code like this:

```
var
  RasEntry: PRasEntry;
  RasBufferSize: DWord;
  Res: DWord;
begin
  RasBufferSize := 0;
  Res := RasGetEntryProperties(nil, '', nil, @RasBufferSize, nil, nil);
  if Res <> Error_Success then
    RaiseLastOSError(Res);
  RasEntry := AllocMem(RasBufferSize);
  try
    RasEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(TRasEntry);
    Assert(RasEntry.dwSize <= RasBufferSize);
    Res := RasGetEntryProperties(nil, '', RasEntry, @RasBufferSize, nil, nil);
  finally
    FreeMem(RasEntry);
  end;
end;
```

You ask the function how large a buffer it requires (in `RasBufferSize`), and then you tell it how large a buffer you're expecting it to fill (in `RasEntry.dwSize`). The `dwSize` field tells the function what version of the structure you're expecting to receive.